# Python Turtle drawing is off-centered

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I wrote the following code:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)
t._delay(0)

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.colormode(255)


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

IMG_WIDTH = 8
IMG_HEIGHT = 8

TILE_SIZE = 32

image = [[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
         [0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0],
         [0,0,2,3,3,2,0,0],
         [4,4,1,2,2,1,4,4],
         [3,0,0,4,4,0,0,3],
         [3,0,0,4,4,0,0,3],
         [3,0,0,4,4,0,0,3],
         [2,0,0,3,3,0,0,2]]

COLOR_DICTIONARY = { 0 : BLACK,
                     1 : WHITE,
                     2 : RED,
                     3 : BLUE,
                     4 : GREEN}


for y in range(0,IMG_HEIGHT):
  for x in range(0,IMG_WIDTH):
    t.color(COLOR_DICTIONARY.get(image[y][x]))
    t.fillcolor(COLOR_DICTIONARY.get(image[y][x]))
    t.goto(x*TILE_SIZE, -y*TILE_SIZE)
    t.begin_fill()

    for i in range(4):
      t.pendown()
      t.forward(TILE_SIZE)
      t.right(90)
      t.penup()

    t.end_fill()
```

and when I run this code the drawing is off-centered with half of it off the screen. Is there something wrong with my code?

drawing:
[image: drawring]

I'm not sure what to really do to fix this, tried messing around with the image grid because I don't know what to do.

Comment: (0,0) is at the center of the screen, so your t.goto() function is counted from the center. Try adding some offsets inside that function like `t.goto(x*TILE_SIZE - IMG_WIDTH/2*TILE_SIZE, -y*TILE_SIZE - IMG_HEIGHT/2*TILE_SIZE)`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I used the code you sent but it just pushed the drawing down even more.  I don't know if I'm doing something wrong on my side but please do reply, thanks.

Comment: Try a + instead of a - in the y portion. Just keep fiddling with the offsets until it works.

Comment: I've tried that but it still doesn't work, using the addition operator just flips the drawing upside down but it's still off-centered

Answer (score 1):

Your current drawing starts from 0, 0, the center of the screen as the top left of your drawing. If you want to center your drawing, loop from -height / 2 and -width / 2:

```py
for y in range(-IMG_HEIGHT // 2, IMG_HEIGHT // 2):
  for x in range(-IMG_WIDTH // 2, IMG_WIDTH // 2):
```

As an aside, I suggest using [black](https://github.com/psf/black) to autoformat your code. 2-space indentation is difficult to read because it's hard to determine which code is within which block.

Answer (score 0):

I applaud @gorlen's approach (+1) but also feel this a potential example of *better living through stamping*:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLOR_DICTIONARY = {
    0: 'black',
    1: 'white',
    2: 'red',
    3: 'blue',
    4: 'green'
}

TILE_SIZE = 32
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

image = [
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0],
    [4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4],
    [3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3],
    [3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3],
    [3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2]
]

image_height = len(image)
image_width = len(image[0])

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(TILE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()

for y in range(image_height):
    turtle.goto((1/2 - image_width/2) * TILE_SIZE, (image_height/2 - 1/2 - y) * TILE_SIZE)

    for color in image[y]:
        turtle.color(COLOR_DICTIONARY[color])
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(TILE_SIZE)

screen.exitonclick()
```